# How can I adjust a UIView for landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, rotation, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a custom `UIView` as a subview.  When I rotate the iPhone from portrait to landscape orientation the `UIView` subview rotates correctly but does not resize correctly. **How can I resize the custom `UIView` when the device is rotated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `UIView`'s `autoresizingMask` like so:

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

This should mean that the view resizes itself automatically on rotation.